# Unable to create new directories in /srv/www

Tags: linux, permissions

`/srv/www` was `root:root` but I changed it to `wwwrun:web` (if this is a bad idea don't hesitate to tell me).

```
user@Web2:/srv> ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root 4096 May  5  2010 ftp
drwxrwxr-x 3 wwwrun web  4096 May  2 14:39 www
```

my user is also in the `web` group and is unable to create directories within `www`.  How come, if we're in the same group?

I do need apache to be able to serve these files.

Comment: are you using something like redhat or centos?

Comment: Slackware most likely.

Comment: We are using `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're actually *in* the `web` group before you start your operations:

```
newgrp web
```

Comment: `groups user` shows: `user : web` so I know I am in that group.

Comment: At least _try_ it before you reject the idea.

Comment: Ah... so you're saying I needed to refresh my groups and/or reconnect before it would recognize I'm in the new group.  That worked.  I thought the command was trying to create the group.